# The time complexity of finding the degree intersection of multiple ranges in a circle

Tags: algorithm, intervals

Given multiple ***degree*** intervals (such as [0, 150], [120, 370], [-60, 50], [-350, -50]), I want to find the intersection of these intervals.

I tried to determine the first two intervals' intersection, and store the result as a new interval, intersect with 3rd interval, and so on.

How can I determine the time complexity of this algorithm? Since it might get two intervals in a intersect operation (for example, **[0, 150]** intersect **[100, 380]** will get **[100, 150]** and **[0, 20]**)

I'm worried that the total number of intervals will be 2<sup>n</sup>, and the time complexity will be O(2<sup>n</sup>). (Although this is nearly impossible, I think. But I don't know how to prove this!)

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Hint: Sort the array first. also a common problem called "intersection of intervals"

Comment: *"I'm worried that the total number of intervals will be 2^n"* No, I think the number of intervals would be at most n. Proof by recurrence: suppose the intersection of the first k intervals results in k intervals or less. You intersect this result with one new interval. How many intervals can there be in this intersection?